# Core Data returns error while sorting and shows empty list in the table with French language

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, localization, french

I only see an empty list which I select my language as French. Below is some code related to that.

```
+ (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsControllerForAirportTranslationsInLanguage:(NSString *)theLanguage inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc_ {
NSLog(@"language is %@",theLanguage);
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = nil;

AirportTranslationFetchRequest *request = [[AirportTranslationFetchRequest alloc] initWithLanguage:theLanguage inManagedObjectContext:moc_];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorCity = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"city" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorName = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptorCity, sortDescriptorName, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

fetchedResultsController = [[[XXXGMFetchedResultsControllerDoubleByte alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:moc_ sectionNameKeyPath:@"firstLetterOfCity" cacheName:nil] autorelease];
[sortDescriptorCity release];
[sortDescriptorName release];
[sortDescriptors release];
[request release];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    LogError(@"An error occured while performing fetch request: %@", error);
}

return fetchedResultsController;
```

}

It works fine all other languages like Chinese, Japanese, Korean.

```
- (NSString *)firstLetterOfCity {
[self willAccessValueForKey:@"firstLetterOfCity"];

NSString *aString = [[self valueForKey:@"city"] uppercaseString];

NSLog(@"ABCD %@",aString);

NSString *stringToReturn = nil;
if (aString.length < 1) {
    stringToReturn = @"?";
}
else {
    stringToReturn = [aString substringToIndex:1];
}

[self didAccessValueForKey:@"firstLetterOfCity"];

return stringToReturn;
```

}

According to the logs below I guess Core Data is not able to process the special chars in French particularly.

> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.543 XXX[1503:60b] CITY YIWU
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.543 XXX[1503:60b] CITY YOGYAKARTA
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.544 XXX[1503:60b] CITY YONAGO
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.544 XXX[1503:60b] CITY YUZHNO SAKHALINSK
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.545 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZADAR
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.545 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZAGREB
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.546 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZANZIBAR
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.547 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZHANGJIAJIE
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.547 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZHENGZHOU
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.548 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZHUHAI
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.548 XXX[1503:60b] CITY ZURICH
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.549 XXX[1503:60b] CITY LAŞI
>
> 2015-03-27 11:51:17.549 XXX[1503:60b] CoreData: error: (XXXGMFetchedResultsControllerDoubleByte) The fetched object at index 1025 has an out of order section name 'Z. Objects must be sorted by section name'
>   2015-03-27 11:51:17.553 XXX[1503:60b] +[XXXGMAirportTranslation fetchedResultsControllerForAirportTranslationsInLanguage:inContext:][Line 69] [ERROR] An error occured while performing fetch request: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134060 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134060.)" UserInfo=0x168429f0 {reason=The fetched object at index 1025 has an out of order section name 'Z. Objects must be sorted by section name'}

Passing `nil` instead of `firstLetterOfCity` gives me the list, but it is not sorted.

Comment: What you have seems logical at first glance. Try adding a sort descriptor for firstLetterOfCity. I don't know if there is some combination of two characters that sorts in a 'unexpected' way in some languages...

Comment: Have you tried using the other sort selectors: compare: and caseInsensitiveCompare:, localizedCompare:, localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:, and localizedStandardCompare:?

Comment: @pbasdf, I have used all four with the below method. But still i have the problem.                                           NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorCity = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"city" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];   how can i used what your are suggesting in the firstLetterOfCity method. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This crash usually arises when you have a **discrepancy between section names and section index titles**.

Check the section index titles array that is returned and compare with your section headings.